# clicking function in android

Tags: android

How do I apply clicking action on listview in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int which, long id) {
        /* your code here... */
    }
});
```